# what are good data structure algorithm for fast 3D coordinates search?

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, search-trees

I want to form data structure for nearby neighbor search for 3D coordinates. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of standard ones, such as:

- [Octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)
- [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)
- [Binary space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)
- [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and their variants

Which one you choose would depend on the properties of your data (e.g. how "clustered" the points are, whether the set of points is static or dynamic) and what queries you wish to perform (e.g. k-nearest-neighbour search).